# How to use my JS variable as an array key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my jQuery, thus far:

```
var themes = {};
themes['blue'] = {
    'background': 'blue',
    'color': 'white',
};
themes['red'] = {
    'background': 'red',
    'color': 'green',
};

$("#colors").change(function() {
    var theme = $(this).val();
    $("body").css(themes[theme]);
```

Basically, I am looking to change the css based on what the user selects from the #colors dropdown menu:

```
<select id="colors">
    <option selected="selected">Colors:</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
```

The following worked fine:

```
var themes = {
    blue: {
        'background': 'blue',
    }
};

$("#colors").change(function() {
    var color = themes['blue'];
    $("body").css(color);
});
```

But I want to add support for more than just blue and more than just the background. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your case you have your key down as "blue" but the value coming in is "Blue" – I would convert these to the same case. You can use variables as key, just as you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your options you used `Blue` and `Red`, but in the object the property names are lowercase.

So either use the same case everywhere, or use [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```js
var theme = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("body").css(themes[theme]);
```

```js
var themes = {
  blue: {
    background: 'blue',
    color: 'white',
  },
  red: {
    background: 'red',
    color: 'green',
  }
};
document.getElementById('colors').onchange = function() {
  var theme = this.value.toLowerCase();
  Object.assign(document.body.style, themes[theme]);
}
```

```html
<select id="colors">
  <option selected="selected">Colors:</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I question my own sanity at times. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case values, because object keys are lower case.

```
var themes = {
    blue: {
        background: 'blue'
    },

    red: {
        background: 'red',
        color: 'white'
    }
};


$("#colors").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('body').css(themes[value]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the multiple color themes support for an application, we can also follow a more robust approach like following.

Update your html and add the following in head

```
<link id="theme-scheme" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Now, for every theme create its specific **theme-{theme_name}.css**, for e.g. for blue you can have theme-blue.css and for red you can theme-red.css

So, now update your function like the following

```
$("#colors").change(function() {
    var theme = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#theme-scheme').attr('href', '/your_base_path/theme-' + color + '.css');
});
```

This approach gives you flexibility to add any style on any element without having additional dependency on script for every style.